# Non commutative flows on the 2-sphere.

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis, spherical-geometry

The title says everything, really. I'm looking for some flows on $S^2$ such that

- They do not commute.
- They are of some interest, or they are peculiar in some ways.

Thanks

Comment: So you're looking for vector fields that don't commute? The action of $SO(3)$ leads to vector fields coming from the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ that don't commute, and these are pretty interesting. A bit more generally you can look at the action of $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: @Qiaochu Cheers! Do you have any reference where I can read about this? (Im pretty new to the field)

Comment: Two non-commuting flows is the same thing as two vectors fields whose Lie bracket is nonzero. This is the generic situation - if I hand you two random vector fields, you should be very surprised if they commute. (I understand this doesn't answer the question you asked.)